# Give examples of following series :

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Give an example of the following series :

(i) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{3n}$ is divergent
(ii) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{3n}$ is convergent

I have tried to find such example, but failed. If we take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is divergent  but what can we say about  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{3n}$?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For the first case, let
$$a_{3k}=\frac1k\qquad a_{3k-1}=a_{3k-2}=-\frac1{2k}$$
for every positive integer $k$.

And for the second case:
$$a_n=\sin\frac{n\pi}3$$

Comment: What is "$-\frac1{2k},$ otherwise"?

Comment: ?? This is not "poor use of notation", this is absurd (what is $k$ in the second case?). Please  correct your post.

Comment: Correct, yes, and awfully cumbersome, see revised version.

Comment: For the second case  we could also take $a_{3n\pm 1}=1$ and $a_{3n}=0$...........+1